# C#. Ошибка при MySqlConnection .Open() The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager'

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void btnReg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = "db4free.net";
            database = "tptappdatabase";
            uid = "w";
            password = "w";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            try
            {



                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SystemLog.Text = "Successfully connected";
                }
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                SystemLog.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.

Comment: Если используете стандартную библиотеку из пакета MySQL, то строка подключения должна быть вида: `server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test`

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: @ГеннадийП Этой ошибки нету когда я запускаю этот же код в Console app проекте

Comment: @NoProgress А в релизе эта ошибка появляется? И попробуйте галочку поставить в свойствах проекта - Debug - Enable SQL Server debugging.